# Console shows only the file-name and content of file together instead of only content

Tags: java, file

I want to show a preview of the content of a file. But unfortunately the name is being shown together with the content. I don't know how to just print the content of it. It's a string method, so it must give something back. And i can't turn it to an void methode, because it must be printed in a System.out.println and void methods can't be printed in System.our.printlns liek you may know. So, can you help me?

Search for "//File preview shows only name of file but not it's content. Why?!" and you will get directly to the position of error.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FilesInfo {

    File datei = new File(
            "C:\\Users\\Elias\\Desktop\\ALLE_ORDNER\\Elias\\BACKUPKOMPLETT\\Uni Kram\\Uni Köln\\Informationsverarbeitung\\WS 2018.2019\\Java 1\\HA10");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FilesInfo main = new FilesInfo();
        main.printDirInfo(
                "C:\\Users\\Elias\\Desktop\\ALLE_ORDNER\\Elias\\BACKUPKOMPLETT\\Uni Kram\\Uni Köln\\Informationsverarbeitung\\WS 2018.2019\\Java 1\\HA10");

    }

    public void printDirInfo(String dirPath) {

        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {

            if (dir.list().length <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Is empty!");
            }

            System.out.println("Direction " + dir.getName() + "  contains " + dir.listFiles().length
                    + "  Files/Directions:");

        }

        else {
            System.out.println(dir + " ist kein Verzeichnis!");
        }

        // Die einzelnen File-Objekte aus dem Verzeichnis "dir"
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {


//File preview shows name of file together with some content.. How can I solve this problem?
            System.out.println("File " + f.getName() + " | File preview: " + showPreview(f, 7) + "...");
        }

    }

    private String showPreview(File f, int laenge) {
        String name;

        try {

            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("the content preview " + line.substring(0, 5) + "...");
                System.out.println();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.err.println("It seems that there is no file!!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error has occured while loading!");
        }

        name = f.getName().substring(0, laenge);
        return name;

//  private String showFileName() {
//      
//      for(dir: )
//  }

    }
}

console:


Direction HA10  contains 3  Files/Directions:
the content preview Java ...

File java-short.txt | File preview: java-sh...
the content preview Ein R...

File raabe.txt | File preview: raabe.t...
the content preview Dies ...

File test.txt | File preview: test.tx...
```

Comment: Just call `showPreview(f, 7)` by itself so you don't print the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that in general, showing 5 characters at the start of text file content isn't really much of a preview especially if the first line contains several whitespaces or is blank altogether. This of course would be different if YOU or one of your applications are creating these files and the first 5 characters of a file are considered as Identification characters. Specific rules have been applied in file creation and content placement therefore 5 characters is all that is required.

The code line:

```
System.out.println("File " + f.getName() + " | File preview: " + showPreview(f, 7) + "...");
```

is a little concerning. You need to keep in mind that whatever is within the **showPreview()** method that is writing to console will go to console before the the line above is displayed. The method itself also returns a file name which is truncated with the use of the String#substring() method (laenge = length):

```
name = f.getName().substring(0, laenge);
```

I don't think you want this to happen. What I believe you want returned is the actual preview text. I also don't think you want the showPreview() method to display anything in console, at least in this case, you shouldn't. The **laenge** (length) parameter for this method is really meant for supplying the desired **Length Of Preview** and rightly so. What you may want displayed in console is something like this:

```
// The ShowPreview() method is passed 18 for length argument
File: java-short.txt | File Preview: This is info on sh...
File: raabe.txt | File Preview: Info on the raabe ...
File: test.txt | File Preview:  Test file for this...
```

Now, I could of course be wrong but if this is the case then your method would perhaps function a little better should it look something like this:

```
private String showPreview(File f, int length) {
    String previewText = "";
    String line;
    /* Try With Resourses is used to auto-close the reader. You should
       always close opened files when you're done with them.        */
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim(); // Trim of leading/trailing whitespaces or tabs, etc.
            // Skip blank lines (if any).
            if (line.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Grab first line with actual text but first make sure 
               there is enough text to satisfy the supplied desired 
               length otherwise an exception will be thrown by the 
               substring() method.                               */
            if (line.length() < length) {
                length = line.length();
            }
            previewText = line.substring(0, length) + "...";
            break; // Only need the first bit of content so get outta here.
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        previewText = "FILE NOT FOUND!";
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        previewText = "ERROR READING FILE!";
    }

    // If the actual file contains no preview content.
    if (previewText.equals("")) {
        previewText = "FILE IS EMPTY!";
    }
    /* Return the aquired preview text from file or
       any error that may have occurred.          */
    return previewText; 
}
```

Below I provide another method to accomplish the same task with the exception that it allows you to supply the directory path to where to search files (it also explores sub-directories within that path). It also allows you to supply a String[] Array of file name extensions you would only like to process (supplying **null** processes ALL files). And finally, it allows you to supply a integer value to indicate how large the file content preview is to be (in characters). Only the first actual line of text within the file is used for preview so if you supply a value of 34323 for example your out of luck, you'll only get the first actual text line in file (unless of course there are no line breaks in file).

Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Displays a file preview within the Console Window.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param folderPath       (String) The full path to the folder to search in. 
 *                         All Sub-directories will also be searched.<br>
 * 
 * @param fileTypeFilter   (String[] Array) Here you would supply a String
 *                         array of the file name extensions you would like
 *                         to process (Search for). If null is supplied or 
 *                         a zero length String[] Array then ALL files are 
 *                         processed in the supplied Folder path and any sub-
 *                         folders contained within it. Each extension added 
 *                         to the array may or may not contain the dot so, 
 *                         either ".txt" or "txt" is considered valid.<br>
 *
 * @param previewCharCount (Integer) The number of characters long the preview 
 *                         text should be.<br>
 *
 * @return (String[] Array) All the file paths found.
 */
public String[] folderFilesPreview(String folderPath, String[] fileTypeFilter, int previewCharCount) {
    String ps = File.separator;
    // Gather up the desired files to preview...
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    String[] filesAndFoldersList = folder.list();
    if (filesAndFoldersList == null || filesAndFoldersList.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    List<String> desiredFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String file : filesAndFoldersList) {
        File f = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + ps + file);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            // A sub-folder is detected. Use recursion.
            String[] fafl2 = folderFilesPreview(f.getPath(), fileTypeFilter, previewCharCount);
            if (fafl2 != null && fafl2.length != 0) {
                desiredFilesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fafl2));
            }
        }
        else {
            if (fileTypeFilter != null && fileTypeFilter.length > 0 && hasFileNameExtension(f.getAbsolutePath())) {
                boolean isInFilterList = false;
                for (String extension : fileTypeFilter) {
                    extension = !extension.startsWith(".") ? "." + extension : extension;
                    String fileExt = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("."));
                    if (fileExt.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
                        isInFilterList = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isInFilterList) {
                    desiredFilesList.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
            else {
                desiredFilesList.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < desiredFilesList.size(); i++) {
        String file = desiredFilesList.get(i);
        String fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
        // Read each file and display the preview...
        String previewText = "";
        // Try With Resourses is used to auto-close the reader.
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
                previewText+= line.trim().length() >= previewCharCount
                        ? line.trim().substring(0, previewCharCount) + "..."
                        : line.trim().substring(0) + "...";
                break;
            }

            // If there is no content found in file...
            if (previewText.equals("")) {
                previewText = "FILE IS EMPTY!";
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            previewText = "FILE NOT FOUND!";
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            previewText = "ERROR READING FILE!";
        }
        System.out.println("File: " + fileName + " | File preview: " + previewText);
    }
    return desiredFilesList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking your time to answer my question! I really appreciate this.Your example helped me a lot!

Thanks!!!!